# How to instance 1 connection class for multiple requests?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, gradle, connection

So I'm currently working on a project that will be using a database but its my first time trying fiddling with it on java.
But I'm already seeing my first problem is how would i make one single file that handles connection while other files handles GET/ADD/UPDATE/DELETE (one for each table) what would properly be the best way on doing this ? 
To not having to place connection values in each file and do the connection

I though about extending the connection class with the other classes but idk if its a great idea.

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Database";
        final String user = "dbuser";
        final String password = "dbpass";

        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {
            System.out.println("Connection successful!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failure.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best approach?

Comment: You may want to use connection pooling (see some examples here : https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe i'm wrong, but i think you need connection pool.
Try to find instruction here https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling

Comment: Hmm ye totally forgot you could make it package private for that (folder) Gonna try it

Answer (score 0):

You could move the database connection related code to a utility class, and use the `PreparedStatement` class to precompile the SQL Query

```
public class doSomething {

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        conn = DatabaseConnection.connect()
        String qry = "Select * from table_name";
        pst = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(qry);
    }
}
```